# Windows no longer boots after converting boot disk from MBR to GPT and back to MBR

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, mbr, gpt

First my system (as it is now):

- Gigabyte Z690 Gaming X DDR4 (BIOS Version F8b)
- Intel i7-12700F
- 32GB Corsair memory
- Windows 10 Pro with all updates
- Samsung 840 EVO 250GB (as boot drive)
- Samsung 870 EVO 2TB (as data drive)

I replaced the motherboard (and CPU, memory) of my PC. Windows 10 started just fine after that but I noticed a few problems, mainly everything running a lot slower then I expected. The first thing I did to try to solve this, was converting my bootdisk to GPT. I used a 3rd party program for this (Paragon) and the conversion went without a hitch. Yet the problems in Windows 10 remained.

But the conversion to GPT created a few new problems. The biggest being that I wasn't able to select Safe Mode anymore. Not from msconfig, not from the boot options in recovery mode. So I used the same 3rd party program to convert the disk back to MBR. The program warned me I would be unable to boot Windows, but I figured I'd just run a repair from a Windows 10 Installation USB stick.

The system no longer booted from disk, I got a message that a file was missing or so (as expected) so I booted from the USB stick and instead of choosing "Install Windows" I clicked "Repair Windows"-> "Troubleshoot" -> "Startup Repair" and lastly, chose the target operating system (there is only one). It took only a few seconds of "Diagnosing your PC" and "Attempting Repairs" before a message appeared:

```
Startup Repair

Startup Repair couldn't repair your PC
Press "Advanced options" to try other options to repair your PC or "Shut down" to turn off your PC.
Log file: \System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt
```

Just for the heck of it, I restarted the system without the Win10 USB drive and low and behold, Windows 10 started right up. I checked if I was able to select "Safe Mode" in msconfig, and I indeed was. I then rebooted in Safe Mode (without network) to see if that helped uninstalling a driver (which it did) and rebooted again in Safe Mode (this time with network support) which also went fine.

Lastly, I changed boot mode back to "Normal Startup" in msconfig and rebooted.

Now I got the same error again as before.

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the
cause. To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "Repair your computer."

If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance.

    File: \Windows\system32\winload.exe

    Status: 0xc000000e

    Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a
          required file is missing or contains errors.
```

This time, trying to do a repair made no difference. It would not boot into Windows 10 anymore.

One solution found on the internet, is to do the following steps (from a recovery command prompt) which I did:

```
bootrec /scanos
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

All complete successfully except `bootrec /fixboot` which results in an "Access is denied" error.

The file c:\windows\system32\logfiles\srt\srttrail.txt only contains a single error:

```
Root cause found:
---------------------------
Boot manager failed to find OS loader.

Repair action: File repair
Result: Failed. Error code = 0x490
Time taken = 1797 ms

Repair action: Boot configuration data store repair
Result: Failed. Error code = 0x490
Time taken = 0ms
```

Trying to do a sfc /scannow results in:

```
sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan. This process will take some time,

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.
```

I removed the Win10 USB drive, restarted the computer and it booted straight into Windows 10! It didn't see all my hard drives for some reason, so I simply rebooted and that made the hard drives appear again. I did notice I actually had 2 more drive letters. E:EFI and H:RECOVERY (I think, can't remember exactly). It looked like the problem had gone away.

I remembered that somewhere along the way, I had changed **Secure Boot Mode** from **Standard** to **Custom** in the UEFI Bios (because that was offered as a possible solution somewhere on the internet). I wanted to change that back so I went into the BIOS and changed it back to **Standard** again.

Rebooted the machine and got an error again. Almost identical to the previous error, but on a blue screen (instead of black) and instead of mentioning **winload.exe** it now mentioned winload.**efi** as being the problem file. I know it gives the black error screen if it tries to boot from MBR, and the blue screen if it tries to boot from EFI. In the BIOS, the difference is trying to boot from

```
Windows Boot Manager (P2: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB)
```

or

```
P2: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB
```

The first for EFI boot, the second for MBR boot. So I went into my BIOS again and immediately noticed it now only offered a single option, to boot from **Windows Boot Manager**. I also noticed that CSM support was - for some reason - now disabled. I know that without CSM support, it **can't** boot from MBR so I Enabled it again. Did a "Save and Exit" and rebooted. Again the blue screen. Checked the BIOS again and CSM Support was still disabled. In fact, no matter what I try, I can no longer enable CSM Support, meaning it won't boot into Windows anymore.

**Even worse, it won't even boot from my Win10 USB Drive anymore...**

EDIT #1: I converted the drive back to GPT on another system, and oddly enough, that made no difference whatsoever. I still get the exact same error. I'm now going to do a BIOS reset.

I'm at my wits end now. Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi... You're my only hope.

Comment: You did so many changes ... You could try to reset the BIOS to its default state, before checking again the important parameters. But just change as little as possible.

Comment: MBR and Secure Boot are mutual exclusive choices, in other words, you cannot have have MBR partitions and still have Secure Boot enabled (since that also implies you had UEFI mode enabled) since you couldn’t have had Legacy Mode enabled

Comment: Use [bcdboot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di?view=windows-10) and [bootsect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bootsect-command-line-options?view=windows-10) instead.